# SQLite in Windows 8 Metro (Modern UI) App

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I would like to use SQlite in my Windows 8 App but for some reason it doesn't work.

I've used this [tutorial](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/05/20/using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx)

Visual Studio does not recognize SQlite as a Keyword and keep's telling me:

> The type or namespace name 'SQlite' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've added the two References (as shown in your tutorial above) and there are also displayed in the Solution Explorer but somehow I can't use them.

what did I miss?

Screenshot could be found [here](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/687/sqlitenotworking.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshot, it appears you did not include the SQLite-net client project.  Setting up the VSIX with the reference you showed allows you to embed the SQLite engine in your application, but it doesn't provide a client access layer, which you can get from NuGet.

Scroll down a bit further in [Tim's post](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/05/20/using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx) to "Accessing the Engine from your app"